# Как сделать деплой приложения next js на хостинг?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, nextjs, next.js

Как сделать деплой? У менять есть различные файлы, я так поняла, мне нужно всё это загрузить на хостинг, и там уже с помощью node js, попытаться собрать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы знакомы с git?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## **У меня то же возник такой вопрос и я нашел два способа:**

связанно это с тем, что на виртуальном хосте ограничены права и запускать скрипты из консоли не выходит, а аренда выделенного сервера стоит на порядок дороже.
Как выяснилось хоста вполне достаточно.

### 1) Первый - генерация статических страниц next js.

Это подойдет, если страницы сайта можно представить без генерации на сервере.(в принципе, node для этого не нужен)
для этого необходимо выполнить **npm run build, npm run export.** убедитесь сперва, что ваш package.json содержит следующий код:

---

> "scripts": {
> "dev": "next dev",
> "build": "next build",
> "start": "next start",
> "export": "next export",
> "lint": "next lint"
> }

---

после выполнения **next export** появится папка **out** в корне проекта - это и есть статический сайт - содержимое папки просто нужно перенести в паблик хоста и провести настройки создав файл .htaccess с содержанием:

---

> RewriteEngine on
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html

---

в момент создания статических страниц **next** не отдает изображения компонента **Image**, т.к. по умолчанию сервер node должен отправлять оптимизированные изображения(но в данном случае node не используется)

### **Решение проблемы с экспортом картинок next js:**

установка и включение в проект **next-image-export-optimizer**
подробнее в документации https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-image-export-optimizer

### **2) Второй вариант - перенос готового приложения next js на хостинг.**

сперва я установил node по документации хостинга, на вашем хосте такая то же должна быть.
после подготовить экспорт серверного приложения - все детали описаны в доке:
https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/output-file-tracing
просто копируете папку **standalone** на хостинг и настраиваете **.htaccess**
у меня этот файл выглядел примерно так:

---

> PassengerNodejs /home/v/valkeru/.local/bin/node # место нахождение node
> PassengerAppRoot /home/v/valkeru/node/HelloWorld # адрес проекта, до файла server.js
> PassengerAppType node
> PassengerStartupFile server.js

---

пример содержания файла **.htaccess** и порядок установки **node** я нашел в документации хоста, можете спросить в техподдержке

Answer (score 2):

Вот статья по теме деплоя next.js приложения - https://nextjs.org/docs/deployment. Самый лучший способ разобраться - начать с этой статьи.

Вы можете задеплоить статические файлы, сгенерировав их с помощь. `next build && next export` и задеплоить на любую машину с помощью nginx.

Бзовая конфигурация nginx для статических файлов будет выглядеть так:

```
 server {
        listen 80;
        server_name your_server_name.com;
        location / {
            root /www/data;
            index index.html index.htm;
        }
    }
```

В этом случае nginx сервер будет отвечать на запрос на 80 порт (стандартный порт для http) файлом index.html находящимся в директории /www/data

Вторым вариантом будет деплой непосредственно node.js приложения. В этом случае сгенерируйте билд и запустите его на машине хосте с помощью команды `next build && next start`. На этом этапе вы имеете рабочий проект на порте 3000. После этого потребуется настроить nginx в качестве прокси сервера, вот ссылка на документацию - https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/. Базовая конфигурация для таких задач будет выглядеть так:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name your_server_name.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

Теперь nginx будет перенаправлять все http запросы на ваше next.js приложение.

Стоит понимать, что существует много способов и соответствующих инструментов, чтобы задеплоить приложение. В качестве альтренативы nginx существует Apache web server (https://httpd.apache.org/).

Для запуска node.js приложений в продакшн есть проект pm2, думаю, он подойдет лучше, чем стандартный next.js. Официальный сайт pm2 - https://pm2.keymetrics.io/ и его npm пакет - https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2.

В качестве альтернативы pm2 вариант запуска next.js приложения в докер контейнере, пример есть на гитхабе - https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-docker. Этот вариант можно использовать вместе с docker-compose для того, чтобы в случае возникновения ошибок контейнер перезагрузился самостоятельно и ваше приложения работало без перебоев и необходимости ручного перезапуска.

Для конфигурации docker-compose добавьте в пример с гитхаба файл docker-compose.yml с содержимым:

```
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    restart: unless-stopped
```

И запустите docker-compose командой `docker-compose up`.
Конечно для этого необходимо установить на машину-хост docker (инструкция установки https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/) и docker-compose (и еще инструкция - https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/)

В завершении хочу добавить, что я не являюсь специалистом ни в одной из перечисленных технологий и самый лучший вариант что-то изучить - это попробовать сделать это самостоятельно. Вы можете попробовать задеплоить ваш проект на собственном компьютере с помощью любого описанного выше способа, а потом арендовать виртуальную машину, например, на yandex.cloud и задеплоить там уже в продакшн, подключившись к машине с помощью ssh.

Answer (score 0):

- Запустить проект npm run dev
- В папке проекта создать файл server.js
  Добавить этот код:

  ```
   const { createServer } = require('http')
   const { parse } = require('url')
   const next = require('next')

   const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
   const hostname = 'localhost'
   const port = 3000
   // when using middleware `hostname` and `port` must be provided below
   const app = next({ dev, hostname, port })
   const handle = app.getRequestHandler()

   app.prepare().then(() => {
     createServer(async (req, res) => {
       try {
         // Be sure to pass `true` as the second argument to `url.parse`.
         // This tells it to parse the query portion of the URL.
         const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true)
         const { pathname, query } = parsedUrl

         if (pathname === '/a') {
           await app.render(req, res, '/a', query)
         } else if (pathname === '/b') {
           await app.render(req, res, '/b', query)
         } else {
           await handle(req, res, parsedUrl)
         }
       } catch (err) {
         console.error('Error occurred handling', req.url, err)
         res.statusCode = 500
         res.end('internal server error')
       }
     })
       .once('error', (err) => {
         console.error(err)
         process.exit(1)
       })
       .listen(port, () => {
         console.log(`> Ready on http://${hostname}:${port}`)
       })
   })
  ```

  - в файле package.json изменить

  "scripts": {
  "dev": "next dev",
  "build": "next build",
  "start": "NODE_ENV=production node server.js",
  "prod": "next export",
  "lint": "next lint"
  },

сохраняем все изменения в файлах

- выполнить команду npm run build
- выполнить команду npm run prod
- загрузить все файлы из папки /out на хостинг, предварительно изменив файл .htaccess по примеру выше в этой статье

Comment: в какой статье?

Comment: В этой, точнее не в статье, а в примере выше. Но этот вариант подходит для статических сайтов. Если будут API маршруты, тогда нужно выполнить команду npm run prod или export у кого что и все файлы в папке. next загрузить на виртуальный сервер и запустить файл server.js

Comment: Поправка, нужно папку .next загрузить вместе со всеми файлами которые есть в рабочей директории и запустить командой npm run server.js